# Iterating through array of models with complex relations in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have done this kind of thing countless times in the past, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why this isn't working this time. I am fairly new to RoR and I was using some new relations in my model, that is the only reason I can think of so far.

User model has the following relations

```
  has_one :profile

  has_many :follower_relationships, class_name: "Follow", foreign_key: "following_id"
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :following_relationships, class_name: "Follow", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :following, through: :following_relationships, source: :following
```

I am trying to list the followers of any one particular user, but the names are stored in the user profile. I have tried doing this:

```
In the conroller: 

def followers
  @followers = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id]).followers
end

In the html.erb file:

<% for i in 0..@followers.length %>
   <%= @followers[i].profile.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

So, I initially tried `for.each` before trying a ordinary for loop. But it always returns

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass):
    2:
    3:
    4: <% for i in 0..@followers.length %>
    5: <%= @followers[i].profile.first_name %>
    6: <% end %>
```

However, putting `<%= @followers.first.profile.first_name %>` returns the `first_name` of the first follower.

Why does calling the first item in the array work when I am trying this but not when I am trying to iterate over the entire array?

Comment: Very rarely would a for loop be used in ruby instead this would be `<% @followers.each do |follower| %>` then you would just use the piped local variable `follower` inside the block. Also just because `@followers.first` has a profile does not mean that `@followers.forty_two` does

Comment: I seeded the database... so all of them have profiles. Also, I did use `<% @followers.each do |follower| %>` as I said in the question but it returned the same thing.

Comment: Then one of the followers does not have a `profile`. Try this and see `User.find_by(id: params[:user_id]).followers.left_joins(:profile).where(profiles: {id: nil})`

Comment: It didn't return anything `#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`. I seeded every profile and user in the database together, so all users present have profiles.

Comment: There is no reason for that error in that location except that `profile` returns `nil`. Try changing to `profile&.first_name` and see where the empty result is.

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: Then that is not where the error is occurring because `&.` is a safe navigation operator and `first_name` would never have been called.

Comment: I just changed it from a for loop to the `.each` and the names printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... if you use a for-loop. You should probably go from `0..(@followers.length - 1)` if not, it'll return a `(undefined method`first_name' for nil:NilClass)` error like you are seeing.

```
<% for i in 0..(@followers.length-1) %>
   <%= @followers[i].profile.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

or better yet, use the for.each and send the error. if there is any.

```
<% @followers.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.profile.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I must have made a typo or something when I was using the `.each`, cause it is working now. @engineersmnky

Comment: @ChandlerWhite the `.where` query method always returns a relation (an array).  the `.each` loops through each index of it.